# How to fix an error in a function? Corona SDK

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

I have a function called CreateGround, it creates a surface under the player and if it already exists on the site of the ground, it moves along the x axis to the width of the platform.
But for some reason it does not work for me and I would like to understand, understand and correct it.

Here is my code:

```
local function createGround ()
  local ground = display.newImageRect( mainGroup, objectSheet, 3, 390, 265 )
  ground.x = 195
  ground.y = yc+(yc*0.9)
  physics.addBody( ground, "static" )
  table.insert( groundTable, ground )
end

local function groundUpdater()
  createGround()

  for i = #groundTable, 1, -1 do
    local thisGround = groundTable[i]
    print(thisGround)
    local otherGround = groundTable[i-1]
    if (thisGround.x == otherGround.x) then
      otherGround.x = otherGround.x + 390
    end
    if (thisGround.x >= width+500 or thisGround.x <= -500) then
      display.remove( thisGround )
      table.remove( groundTable, thisGround)
    end
  end
end
```

Error screen:
[image]

Comment: the error message is pretty clear. check if you do any arrithmetic operation on thisGround in line 73 of game.lua and fix that. we don't know which lines you provided here. at least there are no arrithmetic operations on thisGround in the provided code and the code does not show function _listener. `table.remove(groundTable, thisGround)` should cause an error as well

Comment: With this, I figured out, but the simulator curses on the otherGround, says that it have a nil value

Comment: this sentence doesn't make any sense. if you solved your problem write an answer or delete your post.

Comment: Probably you get nil value error because you try get element from table `groundTable` with index `0`. I'm not sure but this element don't exist.

Comment: Replace `table.remove( groundTable, thisGround)` with `table.remove( groundTable, i)`

Comment: Replace `if (thisGround.x == otherGround.x) then` with `if otherGround and (thisGround.x == otherGround.x) then`